# Is it a good practice to writing to a file should be done in Background Thread? If yes, in what circumstances it is recommended?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am developing a Java Desktop Application and I am creating a file and writing small content to it 10-50 lines.

I am doing this in Main Thread, shall I do this File I/O on a Background Thread?
I understand the fact that any intensive operation blocks the Main Thread so Background Thread is recommended but I dont observe any lag/hang in my Application while doing this File I/O.

So What is the best way or its ok to do small File I/O on main Thread.

Comment: Both options are okay and it totally depends on your specific scenario and desires. Anything beyond that is very opinion based. Try to identify pro and cons and then decide. But it sounds like you already know the advantages and disadvantages of both options.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is: you should write your code so that it is *easy* for you to make a change.

You see, the question "should it happen on a background" thread might result in *different* answers over time. Maybe today, when you do that once in a special situation, it is fine. But what if you start doing it more often in future versions of your program? Then it might become a problem.

In that sense: simply expect that this is one corner of your code that requires updates in the future. So design it in a way to quickly change that.

Having said that, in "general": prefer the background thread. Threads are pretty cheap on modern hardware. And java provides you a lot of reasonable abstractions that make it pretty easy to use background threads (think of a pool-based central ExecutorService for example). On the other hand: response times to users are **always** critical.

Thus I would heavily lean towards a background-thread based solution. Because in 2017 that is the almost a natural thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

You are just writing few lines in file, so why to go for background? it will be better to keep it in main thread so that you can get proper exception handling in case of failure.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted. Writing short files doesn't impede the user interface so there's no need to add the implementation and runtime overhead of Threads. Writing long files might do that, and even call for a user interface update to show progress.